# Unit testing LifecycleConfiguration AWS CDK Java

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-java

I created a new s3 bucket and add a lifecycle rule to it:

```
Bucket bucket = new Bucket(this, "MyS3Bucket", bucketProperties());
bucket.addLifecycleRule(LifecycleRule.builder().enabled(true).expiration(Duration.days(7)).build());
```

Now I am trying to test it like that:

```
template.hasResourceProperties("AWS::S3::Bucket",
        Match.objectLike(Map.of(
            "LifecycleConfiguration", Collections.singletonList(
                Collections.singletonMap(
                    "Rules", Map.of(
                        "ExpirationInDays", "7",
                        "Status", "Enabled"
                    )))
        ))
    );
```

But I got next problem:

```
@jsii/kernel.RuntimeError: Error: Template has 1 resources with type AWS::S3::Bucket, but none match as expected.
The 1 closest matches:
MyClassS388392AE1 :: {
  "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
  "Properties": {
    "BucketName": "my-bucket-name",
!!   Expected type array but received object
    "LifecycleConfiguration": {
      "Rules": [ { ... } ]
    },
    "Tags": [ ... ]
  },
  "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
  "UpdateReplacePolicy": "Retain"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the correct answer after trying to capture the rules and look into the captured object,

Here is the correct answer, and now tests passed:

```
template.hasResourceProperties("AWS::S3::Bucket",
      Match.objectLike(Map.of(
          "LifecycleConfiguration", Collections.singletonMap(
              "Rules", Collections.singletonList(
                  Map.of(
                      "ExpirationInDays", 7, "Status", "Enabled"
                  )
              )
          )
      ))
  );
```

So, lifecycle configurations mapped value should be in the next form:

```
Map<String, List<Map<Object, Object>>>
```

which means the Rules should be like that:

```
Map<Object, Object> rules = Map.of("ExpirationInDays", 7, "Status", "Enabled")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the produced template because your unit test is checking for [{"Rules" :{...}] while the produced template appears to be {"Rules":[{...}]} for the LifecycleConfigurationProperty.

Comment: You are correct, but I tried many things, the main idea actually on how I was created this map Map.of("ExpirationInDays", 7, "Status", "Enabled"), before I always depending on String and String as a key value for the Map, but actually it needs the Object and Object to be used, please check my answer. Anyway your answer is partially correct although I tried it before and it didn't work because the reason I mentioned previously.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).